# Infinite Union and Intersection on $[2, 2 + 3/2n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working on solving the following problem:

> Let $A_{n}=[2,2+\frac{3}{2n}).$ Find $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ and$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$.

But the textbook I'm using doesn't give a lot of examples around infinite unions and intersections.  My intuition tells me that this is similar to a limit problem and that the answer is probably something like:

$[2, 0)$ for the union and $\{0\}$ for the intersection.

Any explanations / help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Idle Math Guy

Comment: What does $[2, 2 + 3/(2n))$ mean, for say $n = 1$ or $n = 2$? What does the union represent, intuitively, and what is the intersection? Does your answer fit your intuition? (Also what is $[2, 0)$ as in your answer?)

Comment: what does the set $[2,0)$ mean?

Comment: [2,0) means that I'm out in left field.  :)

Comment: For $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ means [2, 2+3/2) U [2, 2+3/4)...U [2,2+3/$\infty$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim:
$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=[2,\frac72)=A_1$

Proof:

Suppose $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

$\implies \exists n_0 \geq 1, x \in A_{n_0}$

$\implies \exists n_0 \geq 1, 2 \leq x < 2+\frac{3}{2n_0} \leq 2+\frac32=\frac72$

$\implies x \in [2, \frac72)$

Also, $A_1 \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$

Claim: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \left\{2 \right\}$

Let $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$,

$\implies \forall n \geq 1, x \in A_i $

$\implies \forall n \geq 1, 2 \leq x < 2+\frac{3}{2n} $

Since $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\frac3{2n}=0, x=2.$

Clearly, $2 \in A_n ,\forall n \geq 1$.

Comment: Ok, Union definitely makes sense.  7/2 would be the upper bound on the right endpoint and the numbers on the right endpoint would be increasingly smaller.

Comment: Intersection makes since intuitively too because this is an intersection.  since 3/2n gets closer and closer to zero and this is an intersection the right endpoint will converge at 2.  Thank you both.  Much appreciated.